# focusableInTouchMode behaviour in android

Tags: android, focusable

I accidentally find the difference in behavior of a button with and without set its xml attribute focusableInTouchMode.
As you can see in the picture below, I have an *edittext* and a *button* used to bold the selected text, when I explicitly set **focusableInTouchMode:true** for my **button** in xml file, then I select a specific text of the edittext after that I click the button, it showed me an **error** like this

*2024-03-01 11:10:54.663 20564-20564 IInputConnectionWrapper com.example.wordfrequency            W  getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection

2024-03-01 11:10:54.694 20564-20564 IInputConnectionWrapper com.example.wordfrequency            W  getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection

2024-03-01 11:10:54.702 20564-20564 IInputConnectionWrapper com.example.wordfrequency            W  getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection

2024-03-01 11:10:54.706 20564-20564 IInputConnectionWrapper com.example.wordfrequency            W  getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection

2024-03-01 11:10:54.710 20564-20564 IInputConnectionWrapper com.example.wordfrequency            W  getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection*
and I realize that it didn't perform a click on my button.
But when I don't declare that attribute explicitly in xml file, I do above process again, it didn't show any error and preform a click for me.
***Could anybody explain for me this situation deeply please. I do appreciate all of your contributions. Thank you very much.***
[image]